# How to get the list of best paid apps that are currently on sale or temporarily free on Google Play?

Tags: node.js, google-play

Is there any api is available to get the list of paid apps that are currently on sale or temporarily free on Google Play.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play doesn't seem to have an API endpoint to this...
I believe people scrape a huge list of paid apps to see if it's free today. (It's just a guess)

My suggestion is to scrape a page like this one: https://yofreesamples.com/entertainment-freebies/free-google-play-android-apps-today/
It's updated daily with "free paid apps"